# Change range of yaxis according to current screen data on plotly

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, candlestick-chart

I’m using plotly.py and designing a graph of candlesticks. But I want to change the range of y-axes dynamically according to current data on graph. For example, if I’m sliding the graph the current data on screen is 50 to 100, then change the range in to this. And if values increase or decrease then range also change.

```
df=pd.read_csv('tsla.csv')
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x=df['Date'],
                open=df['Open'],
                high=df['High'],
                low=df['Low'],
                close=df['Close'])])
fig.write_html('first_figure.html', auto_open=True)
```

This is my code.
And the demo graph, you can find [here](https://live.demo.chartiq.com/#demo.chartiq.com)